# What material is my damaged kitchen ceiling?

Tags: repair, ceiling, water-damage, materials, damage

Apologies in advance if the answer is obvious, I'm a complete novice!

We're starting work on our first home including repairs to a water-damaged kitchen ceiling. Someone has suggested to me that the ceiling might be papered but it's really crumbly and an odd texture (it almost feels chalky underneath the paint). Can anyone tell based on my pictures what the material is at all please? If you also know how best to repair it I'd be grateful[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would think drywall(straight line crack probably at a seam), with a texture coating instead of plaster.

Drywall does not like or last when wet. Depending on how wet it got, replacement of the wet section probably needed(a lot wet) to maybe just mud/joint compound, primer and paint.

Matching a paint patch to rest of the ceiling will be hard, usually easier to do the whole ceiling.

The texture coating will make matching doubly hard.  They are usually done free hand without a pattern making/matching tool.  I imagine a mirror on the ceiling in the kitchen would look odd.